# Why does the child element not stay at the bottom of a fixed parent?

Tags: css, google-chrome

**Update: it's a Chrome-only bug, as Josh Crozier figured it out.**

Resize the window vertically, to see why the code below does not work. The child element does not stay at the bottom of the parent. Why?

```css
header {
  background: red;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
}
header div {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>Lorem</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Tested on Win 10 Chrome 47.0.2526.106 m (64-bit): CONFIRMED.

Comment: Adding `top: 0` to the parent helps, but I still don't get the reason.

Comment: Tested on Win 10 Edge: NO PROBLEM.

Comment: It looks like a Chrome bug. If I uncheck `bottom: 0` in the F12 developer tool, and then check it again, it works... it looks like it's a rending bug. It also only seems to apply to elements with fixed positioning. Perhaps a repaint/reflow event isn't triggered on elements with fixed positioning when resizing.

Comment: Tested on Win 10 Firefox: NO PROBLEM.

Comment: I assume it's a Chrome-only bug, as @Josh Crozier figured it out. Thanks Josh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a Chrome bug (as of version 47 and maybe earlier versions).

It only seems to apply to elements with fixed positioning. The issue is that the elements are repainted/rending incorrectly when resizing or scrolling. It's worth pointing out that the elements are definitely repainted/rendered, but it *seems* like they are rendered relative to their initial position when the DOM loaded.

This behavior is likely related to issues [454216](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=454216), [153738](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=153738), and [20574](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574).

One work-around would be to wrap the element and absolutely position it relative to the parent element with the same height as the `header` ancestor element:

```css
header {
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
header .wrapper {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
header .wrapper > div {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>Lorem</div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Specifying `top` or `bottom` of the fixed parent (the `header` in this case) also helps, without a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Because `<h1>` has its own `margin`. Try

```
header h1 {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my question is not clear, I'll update it immediately. My problem is not the margin. Try to resize the window to see what I'm talking about. The h1 will move up-down, regardless the margin.

Comment: I've rewritten the h1 to div, so that there is no margin. Still, the problem is present. In the meanwhile @Josh Crozier has figured out that it's a Chrome-only bug.